# Dual boot with Windows 7 Ubuntu not booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

Have been working on this for about a week now and if i had any hair i would have torn it out by now!

I am a noob when it comes to all things Linux but am learning fast and think i know my way around prety well.

SO have a Win 7 desktop, AMD A6-3500, 8gb ram, single 750gb hard drive, windows 7 64 bit installed on it.

Now i want an ubuntu dual boot to ease my transition away from Windows so have downloaded the ISO vreated a USB and used the GUI to create a 150gb partition for Ubuntu (LTS) and loaded okay. Reboot and no grub screen straight into windows.

Read a few things and have run boot repair (http://paste.ubuntu.com/6563425)

Now when i boot i get the grub screen with all the options but if i try and boot ubuntu, it drops out to a command prompt saying it cannot find the boot.

If i select the recovery mode it seems to time out on an "ata5 softreset: ata5 failed (device not ready)

I have tried various things including Easy BCD as well and nothing seems to work. Even tried Ubuntu 13, Mint but all seem to have the same issue..so akes me think i am doing something wrong each time...

Help!

Comment: You may have to reinstall the grub yourself. Use this http://askubuntu.com/a/367561/169736

Answer (score 1):

You have a nVidia card and need nomodeset for every boot, install or boot after install until you get nVidia driver installed using system Settings.

It looks like Boot-Repair or Ubuntu was installed in UEFI mode, but Windows is in BIOS boot mode with MBR partitioning and UEFI does not work with MBR. But your video card seems a older than UEFI systems. If UEFI involved make sure you get Boot-Repair to un-install grub-efi and install grub-pc for BIOS boot.

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)